# Python: tkinter: creating a custom window prompt

Tags: python, function, tkinter, return, window

I've been trying very hard to attempt to figure out this problem. While using tkinter and python, what method could I use to return a value of a function using a button? Here is the current code I have

```
def choice_message (message_title, message, choice_1, choice_2):
    new_window = Tk()
    new_window.minsize (400, 150)
    new_window.maxsize (400, 150)
    new_window.title (str (message_title))
    Label (new_window, text = message, font = "Arial", wrap = 380, anchor = NW).place (x = 10, y = 0, width = 400, height = 100)

    def yes ():
        new_window.destroy ()
        # Added code

    def no ():
        new_window.destroy ()
        # Added code (same as yes but returns false (??))

    Button (new_window, text = str (choice_1), font = "Arial", anchor = CENTER, command = yes).place (x = 90, y = 110, width = 100, height = 30)
    Button (new_window, text = str (choice_2), font = "Arial", anchor = CENTER, command = no).place (x = 210, y = 110, width = 100, height = 30)

# ....

if (choice_message ("Hello", "This is a message text", "True", "False") == True):
    print ("The Window Works...")
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation of your code. I _think_ all that stuff is defined inside the `choice_message` function but it's currently hard to tell.

Comment: There are a couple of ways to do what you want, but it'd be simpler to use a [standard dialog](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-standard-dialogs.htm). BTW, if your code already creates a root window with `Tk()`, or calls `choice_message` multiple times, you're going to have problems because there should only be one root window in a Tkinter program. Instead, `choice_message` should create a [`TopLevel`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/toplevel.htm) widget.

Answer (score -1):

You will have to build it in different way.

You can create a class which has `self.result` and it has to use `wait_window()` so it will wait until you close window. Then you can get value from `self.result`

You can use this class in your choice_message:

```
import tkinter as tk

# --- classes ---
# you can put this class in separated file
# (it will need `import tkinter`)

import tkinter 

class MsgBox(tkinter.Toplevel):

    def __init__(self, title="MsgBox", message="Hello World", choice1="OK", choice2="Cancel"):
        tkinter.Toplevel.__init__(self)

        self.result = None

        self.choice1 = choice1
        self.choice2 = choice2

        self.title(title)

        self.label = tkinter.Label(self, text=message, bg='white')
        self.label.pack(ipadx=50, ipady=20)

        self.button = tkinter.Button(self, text=str(self.choice1), command=self.on_press_choice1)
        self.button.pack(side='left', ipadx=5, padx=10, pady=10)

        self.button = tkinter.Button(self, text=str(self.choice2), command=self.on_press_choice2)
        self.button.pack(side='right', ipadx=5, padx=10, pady=10)

        # don't return to main part till you close this MsgBox
        self.wait_window()

    def on_press_choice1(self):
        self.result = self.choice1
        self.destroy()

    def on_press_choice2(self):
        self.result = self.choice2
        self.destroy()

# --- functions ---

def choice_message(title, message, choice1, choice2):

    msg = MsgBox(title, message, choice1, choice2)
    # MsgBox is waiting till you close it
    return msg.result

def choose():
    if choice_message("Hello", "This is a message text", True, False) == True:
        print("You choose: True")
    else:
        print("You choose: False")

def about():
    msg = MsgBox()
    # MsgBox is waiting till you close window
    print("You choose:", msg.result)

def close():
    msg = MsgBox('Closing', 'Are you sure?', 'Yes', 'No')
    # MsgBox is waiting till you close window
    if msg.result == 'Yes':
        root.destroy()

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

b = tk.Button(root, text="Choose", command=choose)
b.pack(fill='x', expand=True)

b = tk.Button(root, text="About", command=about)
b.pack(fill='x', expand=True)

b = tk.Button(root, text="Close", command=close)
b.pack(fill='x', expand=True)

root.mainloop()
```

Main MsgBox:

[image: Main MsgBox window]

Choose:

[image: Choose window]

About:

[image: About window]

Close:

[image: Close window]

Comment: You can still interact with the main window when prompts are open. Users could open 12 copies of the "About" window